# How do I change the information that is being presented by my algolia wordpress plugin in my autocomplete drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, autocomplete, algolia

I think it says it in the title pretty well.

I do not know where to go to resolve this. I have tried looking at the CMS for algolia, I have tried looking at the autocomplete.js file, I have tried looking at many files but I am still with no answer.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi David, I would gladly help you, unfortunately the question is a bit vague and probably not asked on the right platform.
Please explain us what you want to achieve on the Algolia forum: https://discourse.algolia.com/

Comment: Thank you for the response rayrutjes, I am 2 days into my first role straight out of a bootcamp. So newb status, shotgun, nubetube etc is where I am at now.

Thank you for being kind!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone runs into a similar problem it is listed in the alogolia help guide, I simply overlooked a step and didn't see how to resolve it. It is here if anyone needs it

https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete/#initialize-the-client